# Angular material menu fires click event 2 times in mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular-material

I have implemented a simple angular material side menu from demo. but this is firing all the click events 2 times in the whole page in mobile browsers. **you can even see that in chrome emulator**. (run this snippet after you click on toggle device toolbar in chrome dev tools).

I searched on it a lot. but no luck. Can you guys find what is going wrong. atleast give me a workaround to fire all the clicks events single time.

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngMaterial']);

app.controller('MyController', function($scope, $mdSidenav) {
  $scope.isSidenavOpen = false;
    
  $scope.openLeftMenu = function() {
    $mdSidenav('left').toggle();
  };
    
});
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#tst2").click(function () {console.log("hai");});
});
```

```html
    
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.8.3/angular-material.min.css">
    
  
    
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    
  
    
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    
  
    
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    
  
    
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.8.3/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    
  
    
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
  
  <div ng-app="myapp">
    <div layout="row" ng-controller="MyController">
        <md-sidenav md-component-id="left" md-is-open="isSidenavOpen" class="md-sidenav-left">
            Left Nav!
        </md-sidenav>
         <md-content>
            <md-button ng-click="openLeftMenu()">
              Open Side Nav
            </md-button>
          </md-content>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="tst2">
       text demo content sidebar left open and close text text
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `click` event by the event `mousedown` because apparently the `click` event is replaced by two events `touchstart` and `mousedown` which are both supported by mobile devices (refer to [this issue](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/1976) for more informations)

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngMaterial']);

app.controller('MyController', function($scope, $mdSidenav) {
  $scope.isSidenavOpen = false;

  $scope.openLeftMenu = function() {
    $mdSidenav('left').toggle();
  };

});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tst2").mousedown(function() {
    console.log("hai");
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.8.3/angular-material.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.8.3/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myapp">
  <div layout="row" ng-controller="MyController">
    <md-sidenav md-component-id="left" md-is-open="isSidenavOpen" class="md-sidenav-left">
      Left Nav!
    </md-sidenav>
    <md-content>
      <md-button ng-click="openLeftMenu()">
        Open Side Nav
      </md-button>
    </md-content>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="tst2">
  text demo content sidebar left open and close text text
</div>
```

Comment: I am doing the same thing as of now. but getting all things in `mousedown` is  definitely a overhead. As I have more forms if i use this i have to to manually check each and every html5 validations. thats pretty hard right?

Comment: I didn't get what you mean but if you want a proper way to handle click events in AngularJS use the [ngClick directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick). It's the AngularJS way to do this.

Comment: `ngClick` doesnt help :(

Comment: What do you mean by "`ngClick` doesnt help" ? It's weird if it doesn't help, because it's the Angular way to handle click events ! And what is the problem of using `mousedown` event instead of `click` event ? I didn't get your first comment.

Comment: `ngClick` also doubles the click event. using `mousedown` in both the places will make the html5 validation to manually validate in javascript. if i can use onclick the html5 validation will be automatically handled

Comment: I don't know why you get the event fired twice but it should not, look at [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/C2YKdJZNwrR9ZoEL2ArU?p=preview) I used an `ngClick` and even with chrome emulator the event is not fired twice

Comment: If you are trying to create forms with Angular, then take a look at [this doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) it explain how forms and validation works with Angular